# HTML Email Format within VBA Colour certain lines red/blue

Tags: html

All,

I have an email which is generated by VBA, written in HTML format. I want to colour a couple of lines in the paragraph red / blue or in some instances blue / red.

Is anyone able to advise how I am able to do this.  In the example below i wish the 'in red below' to be coloured red.

```
 "To key your confirmation, click to go to the <a href = ""URL"">iBuy homepage</a> Please note critical requirements in keying have been highlighted <U>in red below.</U><BR><BR><BR>" & _
```

Alternatively in the line of code below I wish the whole line to be blue

```
 "For instructions on how to 'key a confirmation' in iBuy, please <U>click the link below</U>, which will take you to the 'Interactive GRN Guide'.<BR><BR>" & _
```

Any help would be much apprecaited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way for the "in red below" text would be to use an inline `style` attribute on your `<U>` node:

```
<U style='color:red'>in red below.</U>
```

As for the second item, wrap your text in a containing tag like `<span>` and apply a similar `style` attribute:

```
 "<span style='color:blue'>For instructions on how to 'key a confirmation' in iBuy, please <U>click the link below</U>, which will take you to the 'Interactive GRN Guide'.<BR><BR></span>" & _
```